# How to add tabbarcontroller inside viewcontroller in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios4

hi
     i am  currently working  in iphone  navigation based application. so my app have 30 screen,after  navigating five screen  i need  a TabbbarController . I  add tabbar Controller OverMy viewController ( [self.View addSubView:tab.View];) my application work fine and navigation work perfect but my problem is that after navigating from tabScreen to other myViewController which inside tabbbar controller are not relaods but navigated view controller work fine . 
 so above my code adding tabbar is wrong then plz help me ,thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have to say, that I don't fully understand your question, I guess this is due to the language barrier, but maybe you can elaborate your explanation a little more. However, I think that I understood your problem. You want a UITabbarController (respectively it's view) to be a subview of a UINavigationController. Is that correct?
The answer to this question is simple, but, I'm afraid, unsatisfying your you: You can't do that and even if you could, you shouldn't. Please have a look at Apple's excellent [ViewController guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html). It says:

> Thus, a navigation controller can incorporate custom view controllers, and a tab bar controller can incorporate both navigation controllers and custom view controllers. However, a navigation controller should not incorporate a tab bar controller as part of its navigation interface. The resulting interface would be confusing to users because the tab bar would not be consistently visible.